# Scrapy login failure

Tags: python, debugging, web-scraping, scrapy

The website does have a hidden authentication token, but the [docs](http://%3Chttps://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin%3E) seem to suggest I don't need to override the default here, and only need to pass the username and password.

Looking in the Network tab, I do notice that in addition to posting an authentication token, there are also numerous cookies. Not sure if I have to do anything there.

My code, cobbled from various other people's previous attempts:

```
The website does have a hidden authentication token, but the [docs][1] seem to suggest I don't need to override the default here, and only need to pass the username and password.
```

Looking in the Network tab, I do notice that in addition to posting an authentication token, there are also numerous cookies. Not sure if I have to do anything there.

My code, cobbled from various other people's previous attempts:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from dealinfo.items import DealinfoItem

class DealinfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dealinfo'
    allowed_domains = ['dealinfo.com']
    #login_page = 'https://dealinfo.com/users/sign_in'
    start_urls = 'https://dealinfo.com/organizations/xxxx/member_landing'

    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(url='https://dealinfo.com/users/sign_in', callback=self.login)]

    def login(self, response):
        return FormRequest(
                            'https://dealinfo.com/users/sign_in',
                            formdata={
                                    'user[email]':'xxxxx',
                                    'user[password]':'xxxxx'
                            },  
                            callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        if "authentication failed":
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return

        self.log('Login Successful. Parsing all other URLs')
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        deal_list = Selector(response).xpath('//table[@id="deal_list"]/tbody[@class="deal-list__row"]/tr[@class="deal"]')

        for deal_row in deal_list:
            item = DealinfoItem()
            item['capital_seeking'] = deal_row.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()
            yield item`
```

Comment: You should try FormRequest.from_response()

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some formdata in your login request:

[image: formdata]

You can find `authenticity_token` in page source of the login page:

[image: token]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem...as I have tried passing the authenticity token. AND the scrapy docs say pne doesnt have to override anything but the user and password.

Comment: I think it is required. Especially if the authentication token is being created externally. Anyways try it out, may work, may not. Worth a try anyways.