# Scrapy Log In Incorrect

Tags: python, html, post, scrapy

I have been working on Scrapy for a few days now, but when I go to submit a form_response() in order to login to chrono24.com, it does not work. Right now, it seems that the site recognizes my correct user and password as incorrect, thereby returning me to the login page.

My code is attached below, and I am sure that I am making an error in the formdata or how I submit it, even though the login POST in Google Chrome mirrored what I was sending. Thanks!

I also changed the values for username and password to protect my privacy. Thank you.

```
import scrapy
from chrono.items import ChronoItem 
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class ChronoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'chrono'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.chrono24.com/user/login.htm/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sourcePage = response.xpath('//input[@name="_sourcePage"]/@value').get()
        fp = response.xpath('//input[@name="__fp"]/@value').get()
        at = response.xpath('//input[@name="__at"]/@value').get()



        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid = 'js-login-form',
            dont_click=False,
            clickdata = {'name': 'submit'},
            formdata={
            #'continueTo': '/user/index.htm',
            #'login': '',
            'changeLogInPermanentlyPref': 'true', 
            'email': 'MYUSERNAME', 
            'password': 'MYPASSWORD',
            #'submit': '',
            'logInPermanently': 'on',
            '_sourcePage': sourcePage,
            '__fp': fp,
            '__at': at
            },
            callback=self.parse_after
        )       


    def parse_after(self, response):
        # Temporary to see if it logged in properly
        open_in_browser(response)
        #Below this is the code that I will add later, for now empty
```

Comment: There is a loginToken. You need to token to submit form data.

Comment: I did not see the token in the request though. I thought the bottom three keys were the equivalent of the token. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: By posting username and password inspect through network and in headers you will find POST data login token. This url may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275085/scrapy-login-failure

Comment: It seems that there are TWO POST requests sent -- one with a token and then the one that I am sending. How do I approximate this? I do not think that the token is being sent in the one that I attached.